# UserControl Storyboard objects moving out of UserControl

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I have a UserControl that have a storyboard that moves a control (within my UserControl) out of the usercontrol (using a TranslateX RenderTransform).

When I move the object out of the control it shows on the parent Page (that hosts my UserControl).  Is there a way to just hide it when it reaches the boundaries of my UserControl?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I finally did :

- Use a Canvas (instead of a Grid) as my LayoutRoot of my UserControl
- Added a Canvas.Clip that matches the size of my UserControl
- On the SizeChanged of my UserControl I resize my Clip to fit the new size.

I'd like to post the XAML here but somehow the CodeSample does not work :/  Sorry

Answer (score 1):

At the end of your storyboard set the animated controls visibility to collapsed/opacity = 0. If that animation is too abrupt for you, animate the opacity to 0 as the storyboard progresses. To detect when the animation goes out of your control would be rather difficult. You're probably best off "guessing" by waiting a few tenths of a second.

Comment: I thought of that, but it doesn't do the thing, thanks for the suggestion though

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting the Canvas.ZIndex so that the Control is behind the Parent Control

Answer (score 0):

The Z-Index doesn't work since its outside my UserControl.

I was thinking more like using the "Clip" property, but I'm not really familiar with it :/

Comment: Did you specifya ZIndex on both the control and the Parent Control?

Comment: This should help: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189065(v=VS.95).aspx